# TFS Alerts not showing up in the Alerts Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I've recently moved to a new computer and I am no longer able to see any of my alerts that I setup in Visual Studio 2010 and Alerts Explorer. However, I'm still receiving the alert emails when the events fire. I am using the same domain login and I have the same permissions (administrative permissions so that shouldn't be a problem). I have VS Power Tools installed (version 3.3.40818.0). I have the latest services packs & hot fixes installed for VS and TFS.

When I open the Alerts Explorer, I can only see one system event under the Build Alerts that I can't delete. I want to clean up the "spam" I'm receiving but I can't delete the alerts because I can't see it.

Without me having to go into the TFS database and fiddling around with tables and records I don't know much about - how do I get my alerts back in my Alerts Explorer? My old machine is not available anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the BisSubscribe tool (available on the TFS server) to unregister unwanted alerts, but unfortunately you'll need to search the database for the IDs of the alerts you want to remove. This post should give you directions: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/tfsadmin/thread/01e7d1e2-2f5c-415f-81f3-a28e86be0c93.